# Do I need to address a gap between rafter and ridge board?

Tags: framing

There are a few gaps between rafters and the ridge board in my attic from
short cuts. House is a 2023 build. One gap is noticeably larger than the others, about .75”. Does this present a possible issue in the future or is it acceptable? If not, can I shim or sister another board to the gap or will I need to replace the rafter itself? Collar ties are present as seen in second picture. During inspection it was not noted.

[image: gap photo]

[image: attic, collar ties]

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Answer (score 3):

There's shear loading on the fasteners bridging the slip plane between the ridge and the rafters. As a gap widens at the slip plane, the fastener strength goes down.

For the set of rafters without collar ties, each rafter rotates around a hypothetical hinge located at the exterior wall. That rotation should be partially resisted by bearing against the ridge board. The gaps obstruct this load path. Small bearing areas that could theoretically get crushed obstruct this load path.

I would orient blocks of 2×6 vertically and flat to each rafter (cut to match the rafter slope and to bear against the ridge board). Follow the nailing schedule from [IRC R602.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.3) (item 7). I would implement an item 7 edge nailing size and count to bridge the face of each rafter and its corresponding block.

Comment: Should this not be under the building warranty and be up to the builder to fix?  For simple cuts, seems like care was not taken.

Comment: Structural problems are a warranty issue. Occasional sloppiness doesn't meet that threshold unless there's actual movement.

Answer (score 1):

Popham is right about the nature of the deficiency. I would suggest that one such gap is not really a problem, though, having worked on many aged roofs over the years and seen the results of snow loads and time. The roof as a system is stable, and the sheathing acts as a bridge to prevent undue movement.

If you happen to be up there, stuff some shims in the gap and staple them in place, or install a scab as you suggested. Then forget about it.